# Not found picture Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm a Quality Analyst and i'm trying to automate our system, I have a problem and I need help, I'm using webdriver with java and need to insert an image:

```
    String diretorio = "/img/imagemteste.jpg";
    try {
    URL resource = getClass().getResource(diretorio);
    File file = new File(resource.toURI());
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(idSelecionarImagem))).sendKeys(file.getPath());
```

It's in the folder resource and by the selenium  "image not found", the system should open the image, but only informs the image name, I do not know anymore how to find the image.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should try as `sendKeys(diretorio);`

Comment: I tried but not function, org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: path is not absolute: /img/imagemteste.jpg

Comment: I'm using .. 
but WebDriver this function OK, in RemoteWebDriver does not working, because, the system uses angular and interaction is needed to image shown to the user, if i use sendKeys(diretorio);, when sending the registration image is not found, it may not be just the way. Our server does not have folders, it has only the chrome and the driver, it is not possible to take the image in the project package. I need Help =(

Answer (score 0):

That is a known issue. For file uploads you need to use the absolute path. This should work:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(idSelecionarImagem))).sendKeys(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: I'm using  ...
but WebDriver this function OK, in RemoteWebDriver does not working, because, the system uses angular and interaction is needed to image shown to the user, if i use sendKeys(diretorio);, when sending the registration image is not found, it may not be just the way. Our server does not have folders, it has only the chrome and the driver, it is not possible to take the image in the project package. I need Help =(